# How to structure and deploy JS files for Dialogflow intents for an online store

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to do the following:
- In Dialogflow I want to create an AGENT for an online store.
- The AGENT should include 15 INTENTS.

Now I want to write my code in JavaScript and save it locally and then save and deploy it in a Dialogflow-Webhook via URL *.

My question now is:
Should I create multiple JavaScript files for each of the Intents?
Is there a specific procedure or examples that can help me better?

Many Greetings

Comment: Hi, I agree with Sairaj's answer. If you want to build an online store, make sure that you read the policy guidelines and how to use Transactions API (https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies and https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to create separate js files for your functions called by intents to keep your code modularized.
You can follow [Actions on Google GDG Node.js Sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-gdg-nodejs) wherein the Meetup API functions are implemented in seperate file & exported to be used in the index.js file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sairaj Sawant.

Comment: in https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-gdg-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js
all intentions were edited and written in the index.js.
the code for all intent was written together in index.js.
What I would like to do. Write all Intent in separate js file.

Comment: You can write functions of those intents in separate js files and export them to use in a single file. That is more modularized.